# Mac OSX Apache. Virtual host mapping to "Computers Website", not DocumentRoot as setup

Tags: macos, apache

I am attempting to setup Apache virtual hosts on Mac OSX 10.7.4

I have this in my /etc/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/jason/Sites/testsite/site"
   ServerName dev.testsite.com
   ServerAlias dev.testsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This is in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1    dev.testsite.com
```

Located in /Users/jason/Sites/testsite/site/ this is an index.html file that contains "This is my test site".

When I go to dev.testsite.com in my browser, I expect to the the page at /Users/jason/Sites/testsite/site/, but instead I am seeing a page at the "Computer's website folder" at /Library/WebServer/Documents/

I can't work out how or why this would be and any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Many THanks in advance.

Jason

****UPDATE

I've found that if I replace the DocumentRoot settings in /etc/apache/httpd.conf with the path that I want traffic to go to, it does go there, so it looks like the DocumentRoot setting in httpd-vhosts.conf is not replacing the DocumentRoot setting in httpd.conf.  I'm comparing my httpd-vhosts.config settings with those of another mac I have been successfully runing virtual hosts on for a couple of years and they look the same from what I can see, so I'm guessing there is some setting I need to turn on or off(?)

Thanks again for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

The httpd-vhosts.conf hadn't been included in httpd.conf

I needed to uncomment the following line in /etc/apache/httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Once I did this, all worked fine.